# How do I generate a Set Command to my proprietary MIB

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I finally managed to generate a Get Command to my proprietary MIB with the following python script:

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdgen.CommandGenerator().getCmd(
        cmdgen.CommunityData('10.0.1.134', 'admin', 0),
        cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('10.0.1.134', 161)),
        (1,3,6,1,4,1,4515,1,8,1,1,1,8,1295360,1295360)
 )

print (varBinds)

print (varBinds[0])

print (varBinds[0][0])

print (varBinds[0][1])
```

The varBinds print in 4 different ways was just for the learning process.
Now I have tried to imitate the same script while turning it to a Set Command (without any success). There are lots of examples to get but non fitted. So, I have tried the following:

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, rspVarBinds = cmdgen.CommandGenerator().setCmd(
        cmdgen.CommunityData('10.0.1.134', 'admin', 0),
        cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('10.0.1.134', 161)),
        (1,3,6,1,4,1,4515,1,8,1,1,1,8,1295360,1295360),
        (1),
 )
```

I didn't succeed in generating the Set Command as you can see. And i don't see how can I get it to work. By the way, the OID that I am setting is a read-write, Integer (32 bit) with the following possible values: up(1), down(2) and standby(3).

What do i need to change in order to succeed in Setting the OID with any of the possible values ?

I have tried your suggested script and failed:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import SnmpEngine, setCmd, CommunityData, UdpTransportTarget, ContextData, ObjectType, ObjectIdentity

from pysnmp.proto.api.v2c import Integer32
setCmd(SnmpEngine(),
       CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
       UdpTransportTarget('10.0.1.134', 161),
       ContextData(),
       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.4515.1.8.1.1.1.8.1295360.1295360'), Integer32(1)))
```

This is the error messages that I got:

**Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pysnmp-4.3.2-py3.5.egg\pysnmp\hlapi\asyncore\transport.py", line 56, in _resolveAddr socket.IPPROTO_UDP)[0][4][:2] 
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags): socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 3, in  
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pysnmp-4.3.2-py3.5.egg\pysnmp\hlapi\transport.py", line 17, in **init** self.transportAddr = self._resolveAddr(transportAddr) 
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pysnmp-4.3.2-py3.5.egg\pysnmp\hlapi\asyncore\transport.py", line 58, in _resolveAddr raise error.PySnmpError('Bad IPv4/UDP transport address %s: %s' % ('@'.join([str(x) for x in transportAddr]), sys.exc_info()[1])) pysnmp.error.PySnmpError: Bad IPv4/UDP transport address 1@0@.@0@.@1@.@1@3@4: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed**

What do I need to do in order to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap your OID-value pair(s) into [ObjectType](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectType) object(s):

```
setCmd(SnmpEngine(),
       CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
       UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
       ContextData(),
       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.0'), Integer32(1)))
```

Code above does not really use any MIBs. If you want to operate on a more human friendly terms, you can replace OID with MIB module+symbol and integer with label (as described in the MIB):

```
setCmd(SnmpEngine(),
       CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
       UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
       ContextData(),
       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('MY-CUSTOM-MIB', 'myCustomVariable', 0), 'up'))
```

Here's a [working example](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/modifying-variables.html#set-scalars-values).

Comment: I have tried your suggested script and something is still missing. I have edited my question above

Comment: I found my mistake, I was missing the parantheses in UdpTransportTarget. Now I can run my script without any errors. My problem is that the Set command is not actually done (I perform a Get commanf via a MIB Browser). I managed to perform a Get action on the same OID before (python script). Maybe I am missing a wait, or something like that ? Is there a way to debug this further ?

Comment: I found out again what was missing. Because I am completely new to python I didn't understand, at first, that the setCmd(...) is only the statement and in order to make the Set Command to be sent I need something else. I found out that if I do a next ( setCmd(...)) than the Set command is performed (verified with a sniffer). By the way, is there another way, except for using next, to apply the setCmd ? Thanks for the help, you are doing a great job.

Comment: Now that I have managed to generate a Set Command in the less friendly way (your first option) I tried to do the same but in a friendly way, with the MIB module+symbol and Integer with label. I get errors and don't understand why. The MIB includes (namedValues=NamedValues(("up", 1), ("down", 2), ("standby", 3),)) how should I send these values instead of the Integer32(1) ?

Comment: @MosheS.Not sure what kind of errors you are getting. If you reference MIB (second option), you can refer to the value you are sending by label (such as 'up') or still use SNMP types (such as `Integer32(1)`) or just use Python types (e.g. `1`) because with MIB pysnmp would be able to convert Python types into SNMP ones automatically.

Comment: It seems like my MIB is unknown to python. I have converted it to .py and copied it to the same mib folder where I found SNMPv2-MIB along with some others. Where do I need to put my MIB files ? If I manage to set/get values to/from the OID doesn't it say that my MIB is "known" to python ?

Comment: I suppose that I know what is the problem. I can almost tell that for sure my MIB is "known" to python. And I know that my Get/Set requests were missing crucial info. I sent the MIB module (SL-XPDR-MIB) and the Symbol (xpdrMuxInbandAdmin), but I didn't supply the Instance from which I take the value (i.e 1295360.1295360). So, now I only need to know how to combine the Symbol along with the Instance ? Currently, I have the following ObjectType declaration: " ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SL-XPDR-MIB', 'xpdrMuxInbandAdmin', 0), Integer32(1)) Where do i need to put the Instance ?

Comment: @MosheS. With your example, `0` is the instance ID for a probably scalar value (e.g. non-table). So it is equivalent to `SL-XPDR-MIB::xpdrMuxInbandAdmin.0`. You may try to SNMP walk the whole MIB to figure out which instances are available there (if it's a table). Here is [the documentation](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/docs/api-reference.html#mib-variables) on this matter.

Comment: I actually know all the Instances that I want to read the Integer32 value from them. One of these Instances is 1295360.1295360 (SL-XPDR-MIB::xpdrMuxInbandAdmin.1295360.1295360). How should I write the ObjectIdentity right ? I have tried "ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SL-XPDR-MIB', 'xpdrMuxInbandAdmin', '1295360,1295360')))" and "ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SL-XPDR-MIB', 'xpdrMuxInbandAdmin', 1295360.1295360)))" and got errors. What is the right way to do that ?

Comment: I managed to perform a Set and Get to my proprietary MIB. I successfully managed to perform the Set to the OID + a specific Instance by using the following script line "ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SL-XPDR-MIB', 'xpdrMuxInbandAdmin', 1295360,1295360), Integer32(2)))". By the way I also tried to use the "human friendly" ways with Name Values instead of Numerical Syntax and succeeded